# Cyberpunk/Post-Apocalyptic Sci-Fi series from the 90s or 00s based in Manhattan

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, cyberpunk

A friend and I are trying to find an old book series, probably by a Christian author, that we read in the late 90s or early 2000s. It takes place after the "Water Wars," and fresh water is super scarce.  Manhattan has been turned into a giant prison/slum, all the metal has been stripped from crumbling buildings and they get a very small ration of water from the main land.  A guy convinces a board of trustees on the mainland to take a guy from the island to determine if they should continue to get water by testing his virtue and bravery.  He gets stuck in this cyber-world where he relives events in history from Egypt, Rome, the Crusades, etc. and eventually encounters Jesus or God (in the machine, literally).  We have no idea what the name of these books are except that we're pretty sure that the name "Cyber-" is in the title.  Also, if I remember rightly, each individual book is pretty thin (just a couple hundred pages) but the anthology is a pretty decent-sized novel.  Anyone have any thoughts?

**EDIT:** I am 28 (was 15 in 2000), but tend to read genre fic from above and below my reading level.  I feel like this series was about at my intended level (even though I was reading above it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just found it!  It's called "[Cyberquest](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0849975778)," by Sigmund Brouwer.

Apparently all I needed to do to find it was ask what it was...seriously, we started looking for this thing about a month ago...

Answer (score 3):

You don't reveal your age, but a quick search revealed the youth book series by S. F. Black - the Cyber Zone series. They were published in the mid-to-late 1990's. You can find a quick list [here:](http://www.jacketflap.com/s-f-black/137753) or [here:](http://www.paperbackswap.com/S-F-Black/author/). They seem a loose fit.

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't quite it.  The books we're looking for are a little closer to adult-level (though not much), and much more post-apocalyptic.

Answer (score 2):

A second author, who in addition to youth scifi (Cyber Generation series), has a few Christian books is [Edward Bolme:](http://www.goodreads.com/author/list/133774.Edward_Bolme).

Actually the Cyber Generation series is a collaboration from a number of authors, of which Ed wrote only a couple. See [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=Cybergeneration+)

Comment: Just found it. Thanks!