# Post-apocalyptic religious fiction containing water merchants

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

I am trying to remember the name of a paperback book that I was given by a friend in the United States sometime in the early 2000s.  The book was part of a trilogy that followed the story of a group of people who were surviving in a post-apocalyptic world where water was so scarce that there were "water merchants" or "watermen" or similar who sold water to small colonies.  I do remember that the book was religious fiction written for a Christian audience, and I think that it ended up being specifically marketed as young adult fiction.  I read only the prologue or part of the first chapter, and the only thing that definitely I remember about it was that there was a group of people waiting to meet someone (possibly a water merchant), and there was a guy who was so sick that he was coughing up blood as he spoke to the others in the group.  I also seem to recall that the government in the region was totalitarian and may have been the reason why the water was so scarce.

Other details that I remember are that the cover of the book was mostly blue and contained a sort of cyberpunk-styled image (possibly of a person wearing a hoodie).  I seem to recall that it looked similar to the [cover art for the *Deus Ex* video game](https://www.mobygames.com/game/deus-ex/cover-art/gameCoverId,76646/).  In the book was an advertisement for the other books in the trilogy, and I remember that other books had similarly stylized covers with different images of a different predominant color.  (I think one of the other covers was mostly green with an image of another person.)

What I can say for sure is that it is NOT one of the books in the *Left Behind* series, but it was definitely something in the same general genre.

Comment: Please check whether the answer to [Cyberpunk/Post-Apocalyptic Sci-Fi series from the 90s or 00s based in Manhattan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/38031/98028) is the book you're looking for. If it is, we can close this question as a duplicate to point future readers and seekers to that "main" post :)

Comment: Yeah, that's it.  I saw that answer, but I thought I was looking for a trilogy and the Manhattan, Egypt, pirates, etc. settings for the books didn't seem right.  Your comment prompted me to looked a little deeper into the Cyber Quest series though, and it ends up that there is a type of merchant called a "waterman" who sells pure water.  Thanks.